# Creacion de lista con consulta PHP

Tags: php, mysql

El resultado de una consulta de revision de equipos de un inventario me devuelve 3 registros, el uso, el nombre del equipo y la fecha de la proxima revision.

Consulta:

```
select u.uso, a.nombre, r.prox_revision from inv_articulo as a 
inner join inv_revision as r on a.pk_articulo = r.fk_articulo
inner join inv_uso as u on a.uso = u.pk_uso
where r.prox_revision between curdate() and curdate() + interval 1 month
```

Ese resultado lo quiero mostrar con una lista dependiendo de su uso. Supongamos que hay 3 tipos de uso: Uso1, Uso2, Uso3.

Lo que quiero mostrar por pantalla es:

```
Uso1

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision
 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso2

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision
 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso3

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision
 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision
```

Con el código que he creado me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Uso1

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso1
 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso2

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso2

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso3

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision

Uso3

 - Nombre equipo - Fecha revision
```

Y este es mi código:

```
$consulta = "select u.uso, a.nombre, r.prox_revision from inv_articulo as a 
inner join inv_revision as r on a.pk_articulo = r.fk_articulo
inner join inv_uso as u on a.uso = u.pk_uso
where r.prox_revision between curdate() and curdate() + interval 1 month";


if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
  $texto = "Estos son los equipos que caducan este mes: <br><br>";

  while($equipos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $uso = $equipos['uso'];
    $equipo = $equipos['nombre'];
    $prox_revision = $equipos['prox_revision'];
    
    $proxrevision = convertirFecha($prox_revision);
    
    $texto .= $uso;
    $texto .= " <ul>";
    $texto .= "<li>".$equipo." &nbsp;  - &nbsp; ".$proxrevision."</li>";
    $texto .= "</ul>";
   }
}
```

Alguna ayuda??

Comment: prueba hacer un group by de 'uso'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion podria ser generar un array en el que la primera clave sea el Uso, y contenga a las otras claves. Algo como:

```
$temp = [
 'uso1' => [
     0 => ['equipo' => 'equipo1', 'fecha' => 'fecha1'],
     1 => ['equipo' => 'equipo2', 'fecha' => 'fecha2'],
 ],
 'uso2' => [
     0 => ['equipo' => 'equipo3', 'fecha' => 'fecha3'],
     1 => ['equipo' => 'equipo4', 'fecha' => 'fecha4'],
 ]
];
```

podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$temp = [];
while($equipos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
  $uso = $equipos['uso'];
  $equipo = $equipos['nombre'];
  $prox_revision = $equipos['prox_revision'];

  $proxrevision = convertirFecha($prox_revision);

  $temp[$uso][] = ['equipo' => $equipo, 'fecha' => $prox_revision];
}
```

ahora, en $temp tienes una clave con el nombre de uso, que contiene los valores que te interesan. Ahora puedes hacer una iteracion tal que asi:

```
$texto = "";
foreach($temp as $uso => $values) {
    $texto .= $uso;
    $texto .= "<ul>";
    foreach($values as $valor) {
        $equipo = $valor['equipo'];
        $fecha  = $valor['fecha'];
        $texto .= "<li>".$equipo." &nbsp;-&nbsp;".$fecha."</li>";
    }
    $texto .= "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: SI!! Perfecto, funciona tal y como quería! Muchisimas gracias!